# Should you prefer overloading over specialization of function templates?

Tags: c++, stl, template-specialization, standard-library, overloading

A textbook I have notes that you can provide your own implementation for standard library functions like `swap(x,y)` via template specialization or function overloading.  This would be useful for any types which can benefit from something other than an assignment swap, like STL containers for example (which already have swaps written, I know).

**My questions are the following:**

1. What's better: template specialization to give your specialized
   swap implementation, or function overloading providing the exact
   parameters you wish to use without a template?
2. Why is it better? Or if they're equal, why is this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Short story: overload when you can, specialise when you need to.

Long story: C++ treats specialisation and overloads very differently. This is best explained with an example.

```
template <typename T> void foo(T);
template <typename T> void foo(T*); // overload of foo(T)
template <>           void foo<int>(int*); // specialisation of foo(T*)

foo(new int); // calls foo<int>(int*);
```

Now let's swap the last two.

```
template <typename T> void foo(T);
template <>           void foo<int*>(int*); // specialisation of foo(T)
template <typename T> void foo(T*); // overload of foo(T)

foo(new int); // calls foo(T*) !!!
```

The compiler does overload resolution before it even looks at specialisations. So, in both cases, overload resolution chooses `foo(T*)`. However, only in the first case does it find `foo<int*>(int*)` because in the second case the `int*` specialisation is a specialisation of `foo(T)`, not `foo(T*)`.

---

You mentioned `std::swap`. This makes things even more complicated.

The standard says that you can add specialisations to the `std` namespace. Great, so you have some `Foo` type and it has a performant swap then you just specialise `swap(Foo&, Foo&)` in the `std` namespace. No problems.

But what if `Foo` is a template class? C++ doesn't have partial specialisation of functions, so you can't specialise `swap`. Your only choice is overloading, but the standard says that you aren't allowed to add overloads into the `std` namespace!

You have two options at this point:

1. Create a `swap(Foo<T>&, Foo<T>&)` function in your own namespace, and hope that it gets found via ADL. I say "hope" because if the standard library calls swap like `std::swap(a, b);` then ADL simply won't work.
2. Ignore the part of the standard that says not to add overloads and do it anyway. Honestly, even though it's technically not allowed, in all realistic scenarios it's going to work.

One thing to remember though is that there's no guarantee that the standard library uses `swap` at all. Most algorithms use `std::iter_swap` and in some implementations that I've looked at, it doesn't always forward to `std::swap`.

Comment: "I say hope because" ... This point was noted in WG21 several years ago. All standard library implementors know not to.

Comment: Simple clear explanation: Both case the compiler find best match overloading F(T*) first. But in case 1 it can find a specialization for F(T*) - foo<int*>(int*), so it choose that. In case 2, there isn't a specialization for F(T*), so it choose F(T*). Note in case 2 the only specialization is for F(T), NOT F(T*).

Comment: Why so many up votes? I tested in gcc 4.8 and LLVM 5.0, foo(T*) is chosen for the first example.

Comment: _"I say "hope" because if the standard library calls swap like `std::swap(a, b);` then ADL simply won't work."_ The standard guarantees the library will not do  that, so it simply will work, and so option (1) is always better than (2).

Comment: If I call foo<double *>(new double), it will call the base function rather than the overload.  Can someone explain why?

Comment: @Andrew, because function specialisations don't participate in the ADL.

Comment: Why does the standard allow for function specializations to be added to std?  Is that an omission?  Or is it because function template specialization is just not that useful?

Comment: Did you mean "_only in the first case does it find `foo<int>(int*)`_" (i.e. `foo<int>` instead of `foo<int*>`)?

Comment: "Now let's swap the last two". The last 2 lines were NOT the same. One is "void foo<int>(int*);" and another is "void foo<int*>(int*);"

Answer (score 18):

There's little to add to Peter Alexander's answer. Let me just mention one use in wich function specialization could be prefearable over overloading: if you have to **select among functions with no parameters**.

E.g.

```
template<class T> T zero();
template<> int zero() { return 0; }
template<> long zero() { return 0L; }
```

To do something similar using function overloading, you would have to add a parameter to the function signature:

```
int zero(int) { return 0; }
long zero(long) { return 0L; }
```

Comment: You might use `template <typename> struct Tag{};` for tag dispatching as dummy parameter. that handle types that you cannot construct or pass easily as parameter: `foo(tag<void>{})`, `foo(tag<int[42]>{})`.

Answer (score 8):

You aren't allowed to overload functions in the `std` namespace, but you are allowed to specialize templates (as I recall), so that's one option.

The other option is to put your `swap` function in the same namespace as the thing it's operating on and `using std::swap;` before calling an unqualified swap.

Comment: I prefer `using std::swap;` to `using namespace std;`.

Comment: You may specialize some templates: _"A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."_ [n3337; 17.6.4.2.1/1]

So you may specialize `std::swap` for types not in `std`.

Comment: why you can not overload std functions? is bad habit but std namespace is not special. I do not like it, but many products add std swap for their types in std namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm answering the question in the *title*. For the question in the body about `swap` in particular, the answer is neither: either rely on move semantics, or use ADL.

---

There are **lots** of factors to consider. A few less-obvious ones that come to mind:

#### 1. Specializations are only relevant AFTER type deduction.

#### This affects whether you get any implicit conversions!

Allow me to illustrate:

```
inline long add(long a, long b) { return a + b; }
int main() { return add(0, 1L); }  // OK
```

```
template<class T> T add(T a, T b);
template<> inline long add(long a, long b) { return a + b; }
int main() { return add(0, 1L); }  // error: no matching function for call to 'add'
```

Essentially, every *non-deduced* type ***"occupies" the space of all types implicitly convertible to it***, too.
This is a subtle and key point to realize when designing the API, and it can come to bite you back when the function is actually used.

Crucially, **notice there's no one-size-fits-all answer here**; whether an implicit conversion makes sense for you depends on the API you're designing.

Some implicit conversions may be bad for reasons such as:

- They might be expensive (e.g., `char const *` to `std::string`)
- They might affect semantics (e.g., `0` to `int` instead of `void *`)

Some implicit conversions may be good for reasons such as:

- They might aid usability (e.g., `f(std::true_type())` instead of `f<bool>(std::true_type())`)
- They might be necessary for performance (e.g., `std::string` to `std::string_view` makes `substr()` be O(1) instead of O(n))

The only way to figure out the right answer here is to think through how your API could potentially be used, and to be ready to correct any mistakes in the future. The choice is by no means obvious, so don't expect to get it right.

### 2. Specializations are semantically expected to be usable as a drop-in for the base definition (Liskov substitution principle): they must not violate any assumptions users make about the base template

C++20 kind of hinted at this principle when it started using base *class* definitions to for class template argument deduction (CTAD). While that's not about function templates, the principle still applies.

If you're planning to strength preconditions, relax postconditions, violate invariants, or anything else that might affect users adversely, think long and hard about specializations. You probably want to overload instead.

This of course may not be the sole deciding factor, given I've listed at least other considerations in this very answer that might affect your choice, but it's probably the biggest one. If you decide to go against it, it behooves you to document the choice and explain the rationale, because users **will** be surprised when your template blows up on them.

### 3. Specializations definitively block the base template definition from being instantiated with that particular specialization

Overloads don't *necessarily* do that, though based on current language rules they sometimes might *happen* to do that as a side effect of there being no way to reference the base definition.

This may be a good thing or a bad thing, depending on why you're specializing.

- If you're specializing because your new definition is slightly better in some way (e.g., maybe it's optimized), there's no significant reason to block the base definition. In fact, having it around may be helpful for testing the optimized definition. In such cases, overloading might make more sense than specialization.
- If you're specializing because the base definition is unusable, wrong, or nonexistent, then you definitely don't want that definition to be accessible anywhere, and in that case, specialization is probably better than overloading.