# Simple variadic template function can't instantinate

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, constexpr

I'm aware that `sizeof...(Args...)` yields the number of types in a C++0x packed template argument list, but I wanted to implement it in terms of other features for demonstation purposes, but it won't compile.

```
// This is not a solution -- overload ambiguity.
// template <typename... Args> size_t num_args ();          // Line 7
// template <>
constexpr size_t num_args ()
{
    return 0;
}

template <typename H, typename... T>
constexpr size_t num_args ()                                // Line 16
{
    return 1 + num_args <T...> (); // *HERE*
}

int main ()
{
    std :: cout << num_args <int, int, int> ();
}
```

This errors at `*HERE*` with

```
No matching function call to ...
... candidate is template<class H, class ... T> size_t num_args()
```

i.e. it's not seeing the base case which is defined first. Forward-declaring `template<typename...T>num_args();` introduces ambiguity in overload resolution.

```
x.cpp:30:45: note: candidates are:
x.cpp:7:36: note: size_t num_args() [with Args = {int, float, char}, size_t = long unsigned int]
x.cpp:16:9: note: size_t num_args() [with H = int, T = {float, char}, size_t = long unsigned int]
```

I am using gcc 4.6. How can I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn’t declare a base case. You have a template-free overload of your `num_args` function but when calling a function `num_args<T...>()` this will never be found, for obvious reasons: it will always try to instantiate a function *template*.

You can however *specialise* your function template to perform the desired operation.

```
template <>
constexpr size_t num_args<>()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, this won’t work either since here you’re specialising a parameterless function template and such a template doesn’t exist: your other function template `num_args` always has at least one argument, `H`.

In order to really make this work you need partial specialisations, and these only exist for class templates. So this is what you need here.

```
template <typename T>
struct num_args_t;

template <>
struct num_args_t {
    static size_t const value = 0;
};

template <typename H, typename T...>
struct num_args_t {
    static size_t const value = num_args_t<T...>::value + 1;
};

template <typename T...>
constexpr size_t num_args() {
    return num_args_t<T...>::value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont' get why it matters that the "other function template always has at least one argument, H" -- imagine uncommenting out the first two lines of my post -- when recursing into `num_args<Args...>()` with empty `Args...` surely that should match the base case?!?!? How else can the "safe printf" example work?

Comment: @spraff Again: you don’t *have* a base case. There doesn’t exist a function `num_args<T...>` which could have such a base case. You do have `num_args<H, T...>` but this is a whole different function: it has at least one argument, so a function template with zero arguments is *not* a specialisation of it.

Comment: @spraff: Because you can't have partial specializations of functions.

Comment: I can't get this to work for the same reason: http://www.generic-programming.org/~dgregor/cpp/variadic-templates.html -- is it out-of-date?

Comment: I DO have a base case template which is commented-out because it triggers a different error. Please see my edits to the original post. Also, this function is not partially-specialised, all the arguments remain templates -- `num_args<int,Args...>` would be a partial specialisation

Comment: @spraff You mean you have an unspecialised template (not a base case). This won’t compile because you cannot partially specialise function templates (`num_args<H, T...>` would be a partial specialisation), as I’ve mentioned in my answer.

Comment: What's the difference between `template<> size_t num_args<> ();` and a base case? And what's the difference between `template<> size_t num_args<> ();` and `size_t num_args();`? Per the latter, I've called non-template functions from template functions in C++98 without any problem.

Comment: @spraff The first is a base case. That’s undisputed. However, this only works if there is a general template that this can be a specialisation of, which isn’t the case in your code. As for the difference between a specialisation and an overload, consult the GOTW item or the recent SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7108033/1968

Answer (score 4):

Konrad's answer should get you going, but I think the more idiomatic way such things are usually expressed is with static member constants, so I just wanted to present that solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...> struct arg_size;  // no primary definition needed

template <typename T, typename ...Args> struct arg_size<T, Args...>
  : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + arg_size<Args...>::value> { };

template <> struct arg_size<>
  : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> { };
```

Then you get your argument pack size via `arg_size<Args...>::value`.