# What's the essential difference between these two variadic functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I've [been frustrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108161/simple-variadic-template-function-cant-instantinate) by a simple variadic template function:

```
constexpr size_t num_args () {
    return 0;
}

template <typename H, typename... T>
constexpr size_t num_args () {
    return 1 + num_args <T...> ();
}

int main () {
    std :: cout << num_args <int, int, int> ();
}
```

The above doesn't compile, see above linked question [and followup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109420/why-is-this-variadic-function-ambiguous) for details, yet the following function DOES compile

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> void foo (T, Args...);

template <typename... Args> void foo (int, Args...);

void foo () {}

template <typename... Args>
void foo (int x, Args... args)
{
    std :: cout << "int:" << x;
    foo (args...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void foo (T x, Args... args)
{
    std :: cout << " T:" << x;
    foo (args...);
}

foo (int (123), float (123)); // Prints "int:123 T:123.0"
```

Both seem to be using the same language mechanism, but why is the first one bad when the second one is good?

Comment: Never mind, that’s not really a duplicate, sorry.

Comment: Note that `num_args` can be does as `sizeof...(Args)`.

Comment: Nice tip, GMan, thanks, but this code is intended to demonstrate the syntax of variadics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting to think that the difference is that

```
foo (args...);
```

exploits overloading whereas

```
num_args <T...> ();
```

exploits specialisation.

Overloading can handle the base case but specialisation can't for function templates (but it can for classes) which is why `auxilliary_class<Args...>::value` is idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the first function

```
constexpr size_t num_args () {
    return 0;
}
```

is not a template, so it can never be called like this

```
num_args <T...> ();
```