# Problems with last recursion in metaprogramming

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I have the following (partial) code in a class where I try to evaluate a value against a list of values via metaprogramming in C++11.

```
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    return false;
};

template<GLenum One, GLenum... Others>
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    if( value == One )
        return true;

    // Try out the rest
    return eval<Others...>(value);
};
```

gcc complains:

> ../emul/GLPart.h: In member function ‘bool
>   GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with unsigned int One = 519u,
>   unsigned int ...Others = {}, unsigned int ...ValidEnums = {512u, 513u,
>   514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, GLenum = unsigned int]’:
>   ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:   instantiated from ‘bool
>   GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with unsigned int One = 518u,
>   unsigned int ...Others = {519u}, unsigned int ...ValidEnums = {512u,
>   513u, 514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, GLenum = unsigned int]’
>   ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:   instantiated from ‘bool
>   GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with unsigned int One = 517u,
>   unsigned int ...Others = {518u, 519u}, unsigned int ...ValidEnums =
>   {512u, 513u, 514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, GLenum = unsigned
>   int]’ ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:   instantiated from ‘bool
>   GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with unsigned int One = 516u,
>   unsigned int ...Others = {517u, 518u, 519u}, unsigned int
>   ...ValidEnums = {512u, 513u, 514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u},
>   GLenum = unsigned int]’ ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:   instantiated from
>   ‘bool GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with unsigned int One = 515u,
>   unsigned int ...Others = {516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, unsigned int
>   ...ValidEnums = {512u, 513u, 514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u},
>   GLenum = unsigned int]’ ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:   instantiated from
>   ‘bool GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with unsigned int One = 514u,
>   unsigned int ...Others = {515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, unsigned int
>   ...ValidEnums = {512u, 513u, 514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u},
>   GLenum = unsigned int]’ ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:   instantiated from
>   ‘bool GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with unsigned int One = 513u,
>   unsigned int ...Others = {514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u},
>   unsigned int ...ValidEnums = {512u, 513u, 514u, 515u, 516u, 517u,
>   518u, 519u}, GLenum = unsigned int]’ ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:
>   instantiated from ‘bool GLPart::eval(GLenum) [with
>   unsigned int One = 512u, unsigned int ...Others = {513u, 514u, 515u,
>   516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, unsigned int ...ValidEnums = {512u, 513u,
>   514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, GLenum = unsigned int]’
>   ../emul/GLPart.h:31:43:   instantiated from ‘bool
>   GLPart::Evaluate(GLenum) [with unsigned int ...ValidEnums
>   = {512u, 513u, 514u, 515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u}, GLenum = unsigned
>   int]’ alpha.cpp:8:7:   instantiated from here ../emul/GLPart.h:26:31:
>   error: no matching function for call to ‘GLPart<512u, 513u, 514u,
>   515u, 516u, 517u, 518u, 519u>::eval(GLenum&)’

So it seems like it chokes on the last recursion when *One* has a value and *Others* don't. In this case the template parameters **should** then be empty. Do I need to declare the ordinary eval in another way? Haven't coded C++ in a while so it may be trivial but I just don't get it ;)

When trying to add *template<>* to the first eval it chokes:

> ../emul/GLPart.h:14:11: error: explicit specialization in
>   non-namespace scope ‘class GLPart’ ../emul/GLPart.h:21:7:
>   error: too many template-parameter-lists ../emul/GLPart.h: In member
>   function ‘bool GLPart::Evaluate(GLenum)’:
>   ../emul/GLPart.h:32:23: error: parameter packs not expanded with
>   ‘...’: ../emul/GLPart.h:32:23: note:         ‘ValidEnums’
>   ../emul/GLPart.h:32:33: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘...’ token

**Solution:**

```
template<GLenum One>
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    return value == One;
};

template<GLenum One, GLenum Two, GLenum... Others>
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    if( eval<One>(value) )
        return true;

    // Try out the rest
    return eval<Two, Others...>(value);
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the essential difference between these two variadic functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111089/whats-the-essential-difference-between-these-two-variadic-functions)

Comment: The first function is not a template, so it can never be called like this `eval<Others...>(value);`.

Comment: Tried and did create another error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this tends to produce lots of ambiguity errors, the variation that seems to work unambigously looks like this:

```
template<GLenum One> 
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    return value == One;
};
template<GLenum One, GLenum Two, GLenum... Others>
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    if( value == One )
        return true;

    // Try out the rest
    return eval<Two, Others...>(value);
};
```

The first overload takes exactly one argument, the second at least two. Taking zero arguments probably doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: This works indeed. It prevents very elegantly _specializing function templates_ problem mentioned by Bo Persson.

Answer (score 3):

As Bo Persson said,  said, the first one is not a template, so calling eval will never call the first version.  You want:

```
template<>  //this tells compiler that eval is a template function
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    return false;
};
template<GLenum One, GLenum... Others>
bool eval(GLenum value)
{
    if( value == One )
        return true;

    // Try out the rest
    return eval<Others...>(value);
};
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this either. The problem is that you cannot specialize function templates, just class templates. It might have worked if the call was `eval(value)`, but not `eval<something>(value)`.

Comment: Interestingly this was a example from Wikipedia :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Variadic_templates

Comment: But Wikipedia has type arguments (not value arguments), so the calls rely on argument type deduction for overload resolution.