# Template for handling different type of input

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453025/different-types-of-input-using-template-function) SO post on writing template for reading any type of user input.
I wrote template below. But problem starts when string input is given in place of character or floating point number is given in place of integer. When floating number is given as input to the integer, only data before the decimal point gets assigned to the variable. For example: When we assign 6.7 to integer, 6 gets assigned, but .7 is left in input buffer and . gets automatically assigned to next character without waiting for user input. How do we handle this? I cannot call `std::cin.clear()` unless there is something in input buffer to clear. Calling `std::cin.clear()` when correct data is entered causes indefinite wait for some character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

template <typename myType>
void getInput(myType &data, const string& promptMessage)
{
    std::cout<<promptMessage;
    std::cin>>data;
    while(std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
        cout<<"Entered Invalid data, Re-Enter: \n";
        std::cin>>data;
    }

}

void getInput(string &data, const string& promptMessage)
{
    std::cout<<promptMessage;
    getline(std::cin,data);
}

int main(void)
{
    int myInt;
    //cout<<"Enter an Integer : ";
    getInput(myInt, "Enter the Integer Data: ");
    cout<<"Integer Value read = "<<myInt<<endl;

    char myChar;
    getInput(myChar, "Enter single Character: ");
    cout<<"Character read = "<<myChar<<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

[image: Output is here]

Edit2:
After looking at replies, updated the template function below. Able to handle floating point or integer. But I am not able to handle characters and strings in the sample template function. I can definitely go for overloaded function, but I guess that defeats the purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

template <typename myType>
void getInput(myType &data, const string& promptMessage)
{
    string str;
    char *ret;
    uint8_t status=0;
    std::cout<<promptMessage;
    while(!status)
    {
        do
        {
            std::getline(std::cin,str);
        }
        while(str.empty());

        if(std::is_integral <myType>::value)
        {
            data = strtoll(str.c_str(),&ret,10);
            if(*ret=='\0')
            {
                status=1;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout<<"Invalid data, Please re-enter"<<endl;
            }
        }

        /** Check for floating point data */
        else if(std::is_floating_point <myType>::value)
        {
            data = strtold(str.c_str(),&ret);
            if(*ret=='\0')
            {
                status=1;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout<<"Invalid data, Please re-enter"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Need to see how to assign string type to template type
            // Otherwise we still need to handle this else part
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int myInt;
    //cout<<"Enter an Integer : ";
    getInput<int>(myInt, "Enter the Integer Data: ");
    cout<<"Integer Value read = "<<myInt<<endl;
    long long myLong;
    //cout<<"Enter an Integer : ";
    getInput<long long>(myLong, "Enter the long long Data: ");
    cout<<"Long Long Value read = "<<myLong<<endl;

    char myChar;
    getInput <char> (myChar, "Enter single Character: ");
    cout<<"Character read = "<<myChar<<endl;

    double dbl;
    getInput <double> (dbl, "Enter double value: ");
    cout<<"double value = "<<dbl<<endl;

    string myArr;
    getInput(myArr, "Enter the string ");
    cout<<"String read = "<<myArr<<endl;
}
```

The output is here.
[image: output for Edit2]

Comment: Just so you know, using the formatted input operator `>>` it's very hard to handle integer/floating point value input error detection. A valid integer value is also a valid floating point value. And a floating point value contains a valid integer value as well. You practically need to read strings and then do manual conversion and verification to be able to handle those cases correctly.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your question. Can you provide a minimal example that shows what you mean? Anyhow, two suggestions: Firstly, look at Boost's `lexical_cast` (not sure if that made it into C++11 or later standards). Secondly, why not simply use the returnvalue to give back the result? `auto s = get_input<string>(cin);` is IMHO more elegant and readable.

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: Please show an example of input that is not handled properly.

Comment: updated the post with an example.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I guess it will be lot of code to handle this if we go for reading the string. We have identify the type of the parameter passed (I guess we can deduce this) first and then based on each type, validated the input. I guess for a beginner like me this will be difficult. Any link to readily available code modules?

Comment: @Rajesh [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) (or [`std::strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)) could be used to both convert and validate that a string is a floating point value. There are corresponding functions for converting and validating integer values. And if input validates neither as a floating point or integer value, then it's a generic string. It's not trivial, but it's not very hard either.

Comment: Please don't insert images, just cut'n'paste the text. Also, if you have found a solution, post that solution and don't insert it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

> When we assign 6.7 to integer, 6 gets assigned, but .7 is left in input buffer

`>>` reads an integer and stops when the next character cannot be a part of an integer. Said character could be a space character, or a newline character, or a decimal point character. `>>` doesn't care, it assumes nothing about how you want to process it. Perhaps after inputting an integer you will want to input a character and then another integer. Or a string. '.7' is a perfectly good input in either case.

If you want to e.g. read a line and make sure an integer is the only thing on that line, you need to these things yourself:

1. read a line
2. extract an integer from the line
3. verify there's nothing else there except probably white space

One way to handle such input would be this:

```
template <typename myType>
void getInput(myType &data, const std::string& promptMessage)
{
    std::cout<<promptMessage;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    if (!std::cin)
        throw std::runtime_error("End of file or IO error");

    std::stringstream ss(line);

    while (!(ss >> data) || !(ss >> std::ws) || !ss.eof())
    {
        std::cout<<"Entered Invalid data, Re-Enter: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::stringstream ss2(line);
        std::swap(ss, ss2);
    }
}
```

If you need specialised handling for `char` (for example you don't want to skip white space) you overload your function for `char` just like you have done for `std::string`.

Comment: How to know if template argument is character or integer? I think I may need this because digit 5 could be treated as character or integer. I thought of using "is_integral" to decide whether it is float or int and then using stoll or stof to convert to appropriate data. But now got stuck with char vs integer.  Sorry, I am not familiar with C++ .

Comment: @Rajesh If you want to input a character, you call `getInput<char>`. `5` is a good input, you get the character `'5'` back. If you want to input an integer, you call `getInput<int>`. `5` is a good input in this case too, you get the integer `5`. If you don't know what you want to input, I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: Edited the post with updated code. I am unable to handle characters and strings in same template.

Comment: @Rajesh I think you are overthinking and overengineering your approach. I cannot help you with this, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your edited code that is posted in your answer. I will check this out.