# Is the following statement a function overload or a function partial specialization?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

```
template <typename Function> void for_each_element(
  const boost::tuples::null_type&, Function) {}

template <typename Tuple, typename Function> void     
  for_each_element(Tuple& t, Function func) {
    func(t.get_head());
    for_each_element(t.get_tail(),func);
}
```

Given the above code snippet, do we define a overload function or a partially specialized function?

Thank you

Comment: Neither of those are functions; they're templates. So it's a template overload, I suppose.

Comment: @Thomas: Overload resolution *does* consider template instantiations. Function templates provide a whole (unbounded) *family* of overload candidates.

Comment: @thomas: both of those are functions.

Comment: @Dani: No, both are function *templates*.

Comment: My prof was very keen on this distinction. You can only begin to comprehend template (meta)programming once you realize that a template is a *template*, a thing that can be used to "manufacture" classes/functions, but very different and distinct from its "products".

Comment: @Thomas That distinction seems quite pedantic. I'm not sure what clarity it brings to the discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as a function partial specialisation. It's an overload.

e.g.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void foo(T t, U u);

template <typename T>
void foo<T, int>(T t, int u); // Illegal: no partial specialisation of functions

template <typename T>
void foo(T t, int u); // OK
```

Be careful when [mixing specialisations with overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108123/235825), as it doesn't always work the way you may think it does.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fpartial_specialization.htm

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı: What's the point of posting a random link? Do you have any questions?

Comment: Partial specialisation of `struct` and `class` are allowed, but not functions.

Comment: it wasn't a random link and as far as I've checked recently it is not, too.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading. You cannot partially-specialize functions, and even if you could, you'd have a second pair of `<>`-brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It's an overload.  Partial specialization of functions is not possible.  If you try to partially specialize a function the compiler will complain.  In this case, when you reach the end of the tuple, the compiler uses overload resolution to choose the first function.

Comment: "The compiler will complain" is a really useless argument, and it can be used for anything: "If you say `class X / 2;`, the compiler will complain." is not an argument for or against anything but "you didn't write correct code".

Comment: What I was trying to point out is that it's disallowed by the standard, so even if you produce something that looks like a reasonable partial specialization for a function, the compiler will complain.  Maybe I should have been more clear.

Comment: It's just better to argue purely in terms of the language, since mentioning any given compiler doesn't add anything. People often say things like "what do I have to do to make this compile", or "why is the compiler complaining about XYZ", or "fixing compilation errors" -- but that's all beside the simple point which is "what is the correct way to do X". As is so often the case, less is more! :-)