# What overhead is there in performing an identity boost::lexical_cast?

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

Given a function such as:

```
template< typename T >
void function1( const T &t )
{
  function2( boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(t) );
}
```

What kind of overhead is incurred if the type passed to `function1` is already a `std::string`?

Does the overhead vary, depending on the type I'm `lexical_cast`-ing to?

Is it superfluous to make an overloaded function to bypass the cast?  E.g.:

```
void function1( const std::string &t )
{
  function2( t );
}

template< typename T >
void function1( const T &t )
{
  function1( boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(t) );
}
```

The version of boost may be relevent to your answer, as I understand that `lexical_cast` has received a few optimizations across revisions.

Comment: First and foremost, don't make a function template specialization, *just overload*.

Comment: @Xeo Good point [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading).  Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the documentation doesn't offer anything on this topic, I dug into the `lexical_cast` source (1.51.0) and found that it does some compile-time checking on the types and decides a specific "caster class" that does the conversion. In case source and target are the same, this "caster class" will simply return the input.

Pseudo-codified and simplified from source (`boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2268`):

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
Target lexical_cast(const Source &arg)
{
    static if( is_character_type_to_character_type<Target, src> ||
               is_char_array_to_stdstring<Target, src> ||
               is_same_and_stdstring<Target, src> )
    //         ^-- optimization for std::string to std::string and similar stuff
    {
      return arg;
    }
    else
    {
      /* some complicated stuff */
    }
}
```

I can't directly see any optimizations for other identity casts, though, and looking through the normally selected `lexical_cast_do_cast` "caster class" is making my head hurt. :(

Comment: @Drew: "I can't directly see any optimizations for other identity casts, though" -- that would be just returning the argument.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Consider this link, string to string is very fast.

> All the tests measure execution speed in milliseconds for 10000 iterations of the following code blocks:

```
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME ::boost::type_traits::ice_or<
            ::boost::detail::is_xchar_to_xchar<Target, src >::value,
            ::boost::detail::is_char_array_to_stdstring<Target, src >::value,
            ::boost::type_traits::ice_and<
                 ::boost::is_same<Target, src >::value,
                 ::boost::detail::is_stdstring<Target >::value
            >::value
    > shall_we_copy_t;
```

In our case `shall_we_copy_t::value` will be true, since 3-rd case work for us (`Target` and `src` are equal types and `Target` type is `std::basic_string`).

```
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME ::boost::mpl::if_c<
        shall_we_copy_t::value,
        ::boost::detail::lexical_cast_copy<src >,
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME ::boost::mpl::if_c<
             shall_we_copy_with_dynamic_check_t::value,
             ::boost::detail::lexical_cast_dynamic_num<Target, src >,
             ::boost::detail::lexical_cast_do_cast<Target, src >
        >::type
    >::type caster_type;
```

Since, `shall_we_copy_t::value` is true, our caster_type will be `lexical_cast_copy`

```
return caster_type::lexical_cast_impl(arg);
```

So, will be called `lexical_cast_copy::lexical_cast_impl`, which is very simple

```
    template <typename Source>
    struct lexical_cast_copy
    {
        static inline Source lexical_cast_impl(const Source &arg)
        {
            return arg;
        }
    };
```