# Template specialization, using an other template

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Well I have a problem, I don't know how to put it properly, but I have included the code below. I have cut alot out of the code so that it is alot easier to understand the problem, but it might not work 100% now, it's just to illustrate.

The problem is that the template specialization doesn't work.

E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <swift.hpp>
#include <swift/event.hpp>
#include <swift/event/primitives.tpl>

using namespace swift;

template<class T> void print(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << event::representate(value) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Int32 x = 23;
    print(x);
}
```

The problem here is, that "~" will be printed. So event::representate() points in this example to the function defined in "swift/event.hpp", and not to the specialized function defined in "swift/event/primitives.hpp".

Ok, this isn't really the problem because it could easily been solved by changing the representate function in "swift/event.hpp" to the function body of the specialized reprensentate.

But I am not able to do that because of the following to reasons:

1. It won't work with custom classes, if there is not a std::stream operator << defined for the custom class (as of free functions, it could be possible though).
2. It is not only the event::representate function that needs specialization. But also event::serialize and event::deserialize.

Well looking at point 2; class OStream uses event::serialize and event::deserialize in a templated member function. But the specialization of event::serialize and event::deserialize **must be able** to use the OStream (template) methods.

Well I'm stuck at that point. I hope someone could point me in the right direction!

### Source

**swift.hpp:**

```
#ifndef HG_swift
#define HG_swift

// C++ Includes
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace swift
{
    // Cross-platform primairy types:
    typedef void Void;
    typedef bool Bool;
    typedef Bool Bit;
    typedef char Char;
    typedef unsigned char UChar;
    typedef uint8_t Byte;
    typedef int16_t Int16;
    typedef uint16_t UInt16;
    typedef int32_t Int32;
    typedef uint32_t UInt32;
    typedef Int16 Short;
    typedef UInt16 UShort;
    typedef Int32 Int;
    typedef UInt32 UInt; 
    typedef double Double;
    typedef float Float;
    typedef std::string String;     
} 

#endif //HG_swift
```

**swift/event.hpp**

```
#ifndef swift_event
#define swift_event

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>

#include <swift/String.hpp>

namespace swift
{   
    class OStream;
    class IStream;

    namespace event
    {       
        template<class T> String representate(T& value)
        {
            return "~";
        }

        template<class T> void serialize(T& value, OStream& stream) { }
        template<class T> void deserialize(T& value, IStream& stream) { }
    }
}

#endif //swift_event
```

**swift/OStream.hpp:**

```
#ifndef HG_swift_OStream
#define HG_swift_OStream

// Imports:
#include "swift.hpp"

// C++ includes:
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

namespace swift 
{
    struct OStream
    {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive;

        OStream(std::ostream& os) : archive(os, boost::archive::no_header) {}

        template<class T> void write(T value)
        {
            event::serialize(value, *this);
        }
    };
}

#endif //HG_swift_io_OStream
```

**swift/event/primitives.tpl:**

```
#include <swift.hpp>
#include <swift/event.hpp>
//#include <swift/IStream.hpp>
#include <swift/OStream.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace swift
{
    // Events
    namespace event
    {
        // Events for primary types:
        // Int32
        template<> String representate<Int32>(Int32& value)
        {
            std::stringstream str;
            str << value;
            return str.str();
        }

        template<> void serialize<Int32>(Int32& value, OStream& stream)
        {
            stream.archive & value;
        }

        template<> void deserialize<Int32>(Int32& value, IStream& stream)
        {
           stream.archive & value;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include swift/event/primitives.tpl somewhere.

Comment: Actually I did include it, but the extension was wrong in the example. The example was just to illustrate so, including it doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `const Int32&` cannot be converted to a `Int32&`. So the specialization cannot be matched. Changing the `swift/event/primitives.tpl` to use this instead will work:

```
    template<> String representate<const Int32>(const Int32& value)
    {
```

or you could change the main template to take a `const T&` instead of a `T&`.

With functions, it is actually better to overload than specialize (see [Template Specialization VS Function Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading)):

```
    String representate(Int32 value)
    {
```

Comment: Well, that gives me a lot of boost::archive errors. I can't post them here, because the character size of a comment won't allow me to post that much..

Comment: Thanks, I got it partially working right now. Except the serialization but the event::representate works like a charm!
    `template<> String representate<UInt32>(UInt32 value)
    {
   std::stringstream str;
   str << value;
   return str.str();
  }
  
  template<> String representate<const UInt32&>(const UInt32& value)
  {
   std::stringstream str;
   str << value;
   return str.str();
  }`