# Implementing custom iterator for a dynamic matrix class

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, c++14

Consider part of the following class `dynamic_matrix` which is a container encapsulating a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` with an invariant which states that *every row shall have an equal number of elements, and every column shall have an equal number of elements*. The majority of the class has been omitted as most parts are irrelevant for this question.

**`dynamic_matrix`**

```
template<typename _Ty>
class dynamic_matrix {
public:
    // public type defns
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    typedef _Ty& reference;
    typedef const _Ty& const_reference;
    typedef _Ty* pointer;
    typedef const _Ty* const_pointer;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef dynamic_matrix_iterator<value_type> iterator; // defined below
private:
    typdef std::vector<std::vector<value_type>> vector_2d;
    // enables use of operator[][] on dynamic_matrix
    class proxy_row_vector {
    public:
        proxy_row_vector(const std::vector<value_type>& _vec) : vec(_vec) {}
        const_reference operator[](size_type _index) const {
            return vec[_index];
        }
        reference operator[](size_type _index) {
            return vec[_index];
        }
    private:
        std::vector<value_type>& vec;
    };
public:
    explicit dynamic_matrix() : mtx() {}
    template<class _Uty = _Ty,
        class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<_Uty>::value>
    > explicit dynamic_matrix(size_type _rows, size_type _cols) 
       : mtx(_row, std::vector<value_type>(_cols)) {}
   // ... a few other constructors, not important here...

   // Capacity

   bool empty() const noexcept {
       return mtx.empty();
   }
   size_type rows() const noexcept {
       return mtx.size();
   }
   size_type columns() const noexcept {
       if(empty()) return static_cast<size_type>(0);
       return mtx[0].size();
   }

   // Element access       

   proxy_row_vector operator[](size_type _row_index) const {
       return proxy_row_vector(mtx[_row_index]);
   }
   proxy_row_vector operator[](size_type _row_index) {
       return proxy_row_vector(mtx[_row_index]);
   }
   const value_type* inner_data(size_type _row_index) const noexcept {
       return mtx[_row_index).data();
   }
   value_type* inner_data(size_type _row_index) noexcept {
       return mtx[_row_index].data();
   }
   std::ostream& write(std::ostream& _os, char _delim = ' ') const noexcept {
       for (const auto& outer : mtx) {
           for (const auto& inner : outer) 
               _os << inner << _delim;
           _os << '\n';
       }
       return _os;
   }

   // Iterators

   iterator begin() {
       return iterator(inner_data(0)); // points to first element of matrix
   }
   iterator end() {
       // points to element past end of matrix
       return iterator(inner_data(rows()-1) + columns());
   }
private:
    vector_2d mtx;
};
```

The custom-iterator, `dynamic_matrix_iterator`, which uses a `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag` is defined below.

**`dynamic_matrix_iterator`**

```
template<typename _Ty>
class dynamic_matrix_iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
    _Ty, std::ptrdiff_t, _Ty*, _Ty&> {
public:
    dynamic_matrix_iterator(_Ty* _ptr) : ptr(_ptr) {}
    dynamic_matrix_iterator(const dynamic_matrix_iterator& _other) = default;
    dynamic_matrix_iterator& operator++() {
        ptr++;
        return *this;
    }
    dynamic_matrix_iterator operator++(int) {
        dynamic_matrix_iterator<_Ty> tmp(*this);
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }
    dynamic_matrix_iterator& operator--() {
        ptr--;
        return *this;
    }
    dynamic_matrix_iterator operator--(int) {
        dynamic_matrix_iterator<_Ty> tmp(*this);
        operator--();
        return tmp;
    }
    _Ty& operator*() {
        return *ptr;
    }
    _Ty* operator->() {
        return ptr;
    }
    bool operator==(const dynamic_matrix_iterator& _other) {
        return ptr == _other.ptr;
    }
    bool operator!=(const dynamic_matrix_iterator& _other) {
        return ptr != _other.ptr;
    }
private:
    _Ty* ptr;
};
```

Here is a test-case in which I use a range based for loop to print the elements in the matrix, as well as using the `dynamic_matrix::write()` method to compare:

```
int main(void) {
    std::size_t rows = 3;
    std::size_t cols = 3;
    dynamic_matrix<int> dm(rows,cols);
    int count = 0;
    // assign increasing natural numbers to each element
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) 
            dm[i][j] = ++count;
    }
    int range_count = 0;
    // print using iterators
    for (auto x : dm) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
        ++range_count;
        if (!(range_count % cols))
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // print using inbuilt method
    dm.write(std::cout);
}
```

Now, the iterator-based ranged for loop prints the following:

```
1 2 3
0 0 0
35 0 4
5 6 0
0 0 35
0 7 8 
9
```

whereas the correct output as given by `dynamic_matrix::write` is, of course,

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

In the incorrect output using iterators, we see some garbage elements between the actual matrix elements which I can only assume are brought about by *undefined behaviour* when the pointer of the `dynamic_matrix_iterator` accesses "random" memory in-between each row-vector of the matrix - running this on a different machine would likely yield different values here or something else unexpected if this is *undefined behaviour* as I suspect it is.

**Question**

So given this behaviour, is there a more elegant way to implement iterators for this container? Also, given that a `std::vector` uses contiguous storage why is the above actually happening - are the "garbage" values part of the vectors' internal memory used for allowing expansion of the vector?

Comment: I did think about posting it to codereview, but whilst the code compiles and runs the output is incorrect for my specific problem so I thought it would be better to post it here.

Comment: You are right about that.

Comment: "given that a std::vector uses contiguous storage why is the above actually happening " - because though a vector stores in contiguous memory, you have far more than one vector here. You have a vector of vectors, the prime vector's memory is indeed contiguous, storing the rows. Any given row vector is indeed contiguous, storing its elements. But the *collective* of row's elements are not contiguous *with each other*.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see, that makes sense.

Comment: Iterators are subtle. If you read the requirements carefully, you will find that you don't actually satisfy the BidirectionalIterator requirements (but only InputIterator).

Comment: If you modify your structure from `vector<vector<T>>` to just a `vector<T>` and manage a `row` and `column` count you can get by with a single `vector` and things will be more clear.  Inserting and removing will be less straight forward but since you can easily iterate a single vector it's not hard.

Comment: @Matt If I just have a single `std::vector<T>` then I won't have a matrix object at all - it would simply be a row/column vector in that case.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury you can save a matrix as a vector and index into it as if it was a matrix.  For example `m = [1 2; 3 4]` row(1) =  [1 2] can be saved as `v = [1 2 3 4]` with `row = 2` `column = 2`.  In this way it is saved a row major matrix.  If you prefer column major then `v = [1 3 2 4]`.

Comment: Hmmm, I see, not sure if I like that solution though tbh. Whilst it would make iterator support much easier, the rest of my class would need to be altered significantly.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury There are all kinds of reasons that you definitely want to handle the underlying storage as a single vector for this kind of object. Less overhead, it ends up being simpler, compatibility with matrix libraries (which require a matrix to be in contiguous block of memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectors of vectors are not contiguous.  So your approach is broken.

Either use a flat vector and maintain the dimensions separately, or write a generic iterator for ranges of ranges.

The second is best done with range abstractions.  Store two ranges (which are pairs of iterators).  `==` compares outer range begin and inner range (with all empty ranges compare equal).  Advance is:

```
shrink inner range
while inner range is empty
  shrink outer range, get new inner range from front of outer
repeat
```

Initialization is with outer range:

```
Init outer range
While outer is non-empty And (inner range=front of outer) is empty 
  shrink outer range
```

Where shrinking is from the front.

Dereference is "get from front of inner range".

[Here is an earlier post where I implemented this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37872108/1774667).

Comment: Cheers for this, I decided to change my structure to using a single `std::vector` in row-major format from the other feedback but I'm sure your answer will come in handy for if I ever need a similar data structure.