# What is the difference between function overloading and template function? Which is more appropriate?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization

```
template<>std::string Add(std::string x ,std::string y)
{
    return x.append(y);
}

std::string Add(std::string x ,std::string y)
{
    return x.append(y);
}
```

If we can specialize code using function overloading, why the need of Template specialization?

Comment: This is really dependent on design and use-case, and there's no one "true" answer.

Comment: when an overload can do it then go for the overload, but thats just my personal opinion

Comment: What if you have 10 types that require the exact same calls and two that don't. Are you writing 12 overloads or rather 1 template and 2 specializations? I'd prefer the template

Comment: @deW1 i was asking about the two specializations.we can specialize using  template<>std::string Add(std::string x ,std::string y)
{
 return x.append(y);
}but we can also specialize using function overloading .right        
    std::string Add(std::string x ,std::string y)
{
 return x.append(y);
}

Comment: @deW1 I dont think the answer to your (rhetorical?) question is that obvious. If I want to prevent a 13th type to be passed as parameter I prefer overloads rather than template vodoo (though I am still a c++11 guy where sfinae is still more arcane than it is nowadays)

Comment: who wrote `Add` in the first place? Why is it a template? That would be relevant to answer your question

Comment: I know, I was just giving an example of when it might be a bit clearer what the advantages are. In the end it's as @Someprogrammerdude said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template Specialization VS Function Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading)

Answer (score 1):

Because depending on the use case, you sometimes write containers/functions that are generic, i.e., they work for every type. Like for example `std::vector`. However, the meaning of a vector is not the same when you do `std::vector<string>` and `std::vector<const char*>` (while both represent strings), because one stores strings and the other stores pointers to null terminated strings. So how would you solve this problem from a design point of view?

Well, you either ignore the problem with this type, or prevent using this type, or **write a specialization** that makes this container work differently for this kind of type to achieve your design purpose. Similarly, you write a specialization for your function, depending on the problem you're trying to solve.

So, these template specialization are there to solve a specific kind of problem. If you don't need it, don't use it. You don't need to complicate your code for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

> If we can specialize code using function overloading.why the need of Template specialization

Because are different things with different behaviors.

A practical example.

The following example compile and link without problem

```
#include <string>

void foo (std::string const &)
 { }

int main ()
 {
   foo("abc");
 }
```

Observe that `"abc"` can be converted to a `std::string` but isn't a `std::string` (is a `char const [4]`).

So, calling a regular (non-template) function, the arguments are converted, when necessary.

Observe the following code

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void foo (T const &);

template <>
void foo (std::string const &)
 { }

int main ()
 {
   foo("abc");
 }
```

Now the code compile but doesn't link: `foo()` is a template (only declared) template function with only the `std::string` full specialization defined.

This time, the compiler **deduce** the type of the argument (`char const [4]`, different from `std::string`) so gives a liner error because the general version of `foo()` isn't defined.

This way you can impose that `foo()` can be called only with a `std::string`, not with a value convertible to `std::string`.

You can obtain the same thing, mixing overloading and template, obtaining a compilation (not linking) error as follows

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
void foo (T const &) = delete;

void foo (std::string const &)
 { }

int main ()
 {
   foo("abc");
 }
```

Now the non-template `foo()` can (theoretically) accept a `char cont [4]`, **but** is declared (and deleted) the template version. So, given again that `char const [4]` isn't a `std::string`, the compiler give the precedence to the template version. That is deleted. So the compilation error.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the use case.
Consider a function Add() which excepts two variables and returns the sum. Now based on a use case, the two variables can be integers or float. This can be achieved in following two ways :

```
Template <typename T>
T Add(T x, T y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

OR, you can write two functions separately. One for integer and one for float parameters.

```
int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

and,

```
float Add(float x, float y)
{
     return x + y;
}
```