# Specializing template function with empty angle brackets: Does it make a difference without it?

Tags: c++

Is there a practical difference between the following two ways to specialize/overload `f`? Note the difference in the lines above the specialized/overloaded `f`.

```
template <typename T>
T f(T x) {
  return x;
}

template<>
int f(int x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

and

```
template <typename T>
T f(T x) {
  return x;
}

int f(int x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

Comment: In this case no.  related/dupe for the generic question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading

Comment: Also note that the second example is an overload, not a specialization.  A specialization has to have the `template` keyword in it.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I think there can be some obscure differences. For example, what is `f({42})`?

Comment: Even better example: if you specialize, then `f<int>(42)` refers to the specialization. If you overload, then `f<int>(42)` will ignore the overload.

Comment: @Brian It depends.  In the first code it will fail to compile since no type can be deduced.  In the second example it would call the int overload.