# How do I define an explicit specialization of a template member function in .cpp file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to move an explicit specialization of a template member function to a .cpp file, but the linker keeps saying "unresolved external symbol".

Foo.hpp

```cpp
struct Color {};

class Foo
{
public:
  template<typename T> int add(T b);
  template<> int add(Color b);
};

template<typename T>
int Foo::add(T b)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Foo.cpp

```cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"

template<>
int Foo::add(Color b)
{
  return 0;
}
template int Foo::add(Color b);
```

Bar.cpp

```cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"

void f() {
  Foo dbg;
  dbg.add(5);
  dbg.add(Color());
}
```

I tried to explicitly instantiate the member function in Foo.cpp. Why doesn't this have any effect?

I'm aware of two solutions: I could move the definition of `int Foo::add(Color)` into the .hpp, and mark it inline. Or I could force the instantiation in Foo.cpp like this:

```cpp
void dummy() {
  Foo().add(Color());
}
```

How come I can't use `template int Foo::add(Color b)` to instantiate the function? Am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: Just create a function overload without function template specialization i.e. `int add(Color)`.

Comment: @aep Yes, that works, thank you. But. Why. I'm confused. What's the point of explicit full specialization, then?

Comment: Well function specialisation & overloading are different from the compiler point of view. I don't want to go into details, but follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading.

Comment: I must admit I stumbled over the same syntax issue like you. With the help of answer, I got the [**sample**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eef3cb6f3983b0b0) running. And, yes, you were right. Template specializations can be in a translation unit. (There is only one possible implementation which the linker can pick up.) My fault... :-( (but, hey, I learned something.) :-)

Comment: @Scheff All good. If you could learn something from my ignorance then SO fulfills its purpose. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I *think* you're trying to do this.

In Foo.h

```
struct Color {};

class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T> int add(T b);
};

// declare, but do not implement, specialization
template<>
int Foo::add<Color>(Color c);

// general implementation
template<typename T>
int Foo::add(T b)
{
    return 0;
}
```

In Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

// explicitly implement
template<>
int Foo::add<Color>(Color b)
{
    return 42;
}
```

Finally, main.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout << f.add(Color()) << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
42
```

Comment: Oh, so I was using the wrong syntax to declare the specialization! Thank you! I learned something new today.