# If templates are a way to allow any type, what's the point of defining multiple parameters?

Tags: c++

I'm revising C++ after a while, so please bear my curiosity :). Let's suppose we have a function that uses a template as follows:

```
template<typename T>
void print_array(T numbers[], T n)
{
   //some code
}
```

What's the point of trying to define more template parameters, i.e.

```
template<typename T, typename Z> //2nd param Z
void print_array(T numbers[], Z n)
{
   //some code
}
```

If it yields the same exact results/behavior?

Also from my understanding of templates, is that they were introduced to basically allow you to use a function for different inputs regardless of the parameter data types or even the function return type itself. As a matter of fact, even `T print_array(T numbers[], T n)` works, albeit there was a warning regarding no return.

So what is even the point of function overloading then if templates are basically a way to handle various parameters and types regardless how the function is called?

Comment: They don't yield the same result. For the first you expect only one type to be provided (`T`), for the other you expect two, potentially different, types.

Comment: Because it's not the same behavior. What you first wrote is *very* specific. Write just you first version and try executing it with a `double arr[5];` and a size of 5. I.e. `print_array(arr, 5);` and see what happens. Unrelated, neither of these should emit a warning about a missing return, so if you're getting that the code you posted is not the code delivering that warning.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh i see why they yielded same results, because my array is int, and so is the 2nd param. `int numbers[SIZE];`. but if array is double then T will be determined as double, and so the second param has to be double as well...

Comment: @WhozCraig this is the warning I got: `main.cpp:51:30:   required from here
main.cpp:26:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: bruh why the post got flagged for closure ... come on, so we cant be curious anymore?

Comment: That warning is likely for your `main`, not these functions. Neither of these have non-void return types, so they can't possibly trigger that.

Comment: @WhozCraig right but this warning only shows up if i change function type from void -> T

Comment: Well yeah, then your return type is no longer `void`. Again, that's *not* the code you posted here.

Comment: @WhozCraig gotcha thanks. and what about the function overloading statement. Im curious what is the point of function overloading now given that templates exists and thus we can use the same function name for different parameters in the same fashion

Comment: Overloading is not the same. Many Q&As on the subject on this site, [Here's just one of many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading).

Comment: In this example, since `n` is clearly meant to represent the number of elements in the array, there is no need to template it. Just use `int` or better `size_t` instead, eg: `template<typename T> void print_array(T arr[], size_t n)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thats the first thing I thought may work, however, that means the size of the array MUST be constant, since size_t or int n would be considered a nontype

Comment: @Cataster "*that means the size of the array MUST be constant*" - not true. It will work just fine with fixed arrays and dynamic arrays alike, eg: `double arr[5];... print_array(arr, 5);` ... `int n = 10; int *array = new int[n];... print_array(arr, n);`

Comment: @Cataster You are thinking of a non-type template parameter, as in `template <typename T, size_t n>...`. `n` in `print_array(T arr[], size_t n)` is just a regular function parameter. You can happily pass a value determined at runtime there, it doesn't have to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: If you want a function that can be called with two arguments, and the types of those arguments are completely unrelated, your first approach would be useless.

Comment: Template is just that - a template. Template functions do not exist until you instantiate them by providing all template parameters they need. This means that template functions can only be used when you have the whole template definition (the function body). Try writing a template function with declaration in header and sources in source file. Try using it in separate source file. It won't work this way because you try to use a function without a definition and in place of template definition  you do not know how it will be used.

Comment: E.g. look at std::map template type. It maps keys of one type to values of another type. You want to specify two different types as template parameters.